# Python 2.X - Custom Print statement

Tags: python, function, overloading

I want to overload `print` statement for my own class. 
For example, I have my class named Character_Dict and defined as below:

```
class Character_Dict(object):
    def __init__(self, key_length):
        self.char_dict = {}
        self.ASCII_dict = {}
        self.key_length = key_length
        self.dictionary = self.char_dict
        self.current_character = ''
```

For the need of example we have an object named `char_dict_object`, which is an instance of `Character_Dict` class.

How can I change `print` statement to get my `self.current_character` printed by using `print char_dict_object`?
Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: where is `char_dict_object`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Somewhere out of `Character_Dict` class, in my "main" function. Does the location of it change anything?

Comment: I was just asking as it is a bit unclear what you are trying to do. It is an instance of Character_Dict?

Comment: Yes, it is :). I will edit question to mark it there :) When my program would be finished I can post link to GitHub repository if you are curious.